# Can't transfer list<T> to web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the same classes on my server and on my web service.
I have the following WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
        public int CreateOrder(List<Purchase> p, string username)
        {
            o.Add(new Order(p,username));

            return o.Count;
        }
```

However the following code, run at server:

```
protected void CartRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Purchase> l = ((List<Purchase>)Session["Cart"]);

        if (e.CommandName == "Order")
        {
            localhost.ValidateService WS = new localhost.ValidateService();
            WS.CreateOrder(l, Session["username"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

gives the following error: `Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Purchase>' to 'localhost.Purchase[]'`.

How can I transfer the `list<Purchase>` object to the web service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using web services like that, by default `List<T>` gets converted into an array (`T[]`). Convert your list into an array by doing `.ToArray()` before passing it to the method.

Another option is to change the web service code generation settings to use lists instead of arrays.

It seems you also have duplicate classes, both a local one called `Purchase` and the one that's generated over the web service, also called `Purchase`. Even though they have the same name, they're two different types (their namespaces are different). You'll either have to stick to one set of types, or use something like [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map between your two sets of types.

Comment: Still no luck. Error is `Argument '1': cannot convert from 'Purchase[]' to 'localhost.Purchase[]'`

Comment: @iTayb 'Purchase' != 'localhost.Purchase'

Comment: How can I use only one of them? They aren't on the same server.

Comment: AS @Matti said, you probably have two definitions for your Purchase class, one defined in the proxy code, and one in a shared reference assembly. Either edit the References.cs file to remove the duplicate definition, or if you are using VS to generate the proxy then regenerate it and untick the 'reuse shared assemblies' tickbox.

Comment: Sorry, But I didn't manage to do either one of both solutions.
Where is that References.cs and what needed to be edited in it?
Where is "reuse shared assemblies" located?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `svcutil` to generate the client proxy classes, you can use the `collectionType` option to force the proxies to use a type other than the default array. This is certainly what gets used for generating proxies to WCF services; I'm not 100% sure if it's used with ASMX services.

Anyway, this is achieved by doing:

```
svcutil.exe /collectionType:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [service url]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the webservice uses SOAP to transfer the data, which is an XML protocol.
It knows nothing about .NET lists or many other fancy objects.

So in your case, it is actually transferring an array, and as Matti already said the solution is then simply to use an Array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize List<T> into xml, the <T> bit will obviously turn into a badly formed xml tag.

You could make a new object that inherits from List<T>, which will then serialize nicely and go through your web service, this is a minefield of best practice no-nos but you need to compromise sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

localohost.ValidateService is a proxy class, with his own namespaces for classes: then "Order" is not the same as "localhost.Order"

if your calling web service from an other method in ther same web service class,
try this:

tihs.CreateOrder(l, Session["username"].ToString());