# Get a value from KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, .net

This method is called via jQuery and populates a dropdown box. It has worked before until I need to add some additional information to the dropdown text. I'm trying to pass an ID into the second stored proc and place that value beside the first value in my KeyValuePair. I'm not sure how to get that ID to pass in though. Any ideas?

```
   [WebMethod]
//public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadRestByCityState(string city, string state)
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> LoadRestByCityState(string city, string state)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString.Data"]);
    DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_RestByCityState_p");
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pCity", DbType.String, city);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pState", DbType.String, state);
    ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

    KeyValuePair<string, string> parks = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();

    DataSet dset = new DataSet();

    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Select a restaurant", "0"));
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DbCommand comm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.sel_RestDetailsByID_p");
        db.AddInParameter(comm, "@pRestId", DbType.Int32, //keyvalueid );
        db.AddInParameter(comm, "@pAttributeCode", DbType.String, "Detail");
        dset = db.ExecuteDataSet(comm);

        string attr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AttributeValue"].ToString();

        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(row[0].ToString() + " - " + attr, row[1].ToString()));

    }

    return list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly clear what your problem is, but I think that the line

```
string attr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AttributeValue"].ToString();
```

should read

```
string attr = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AttributeValue"].ToString();
```

You are looking at the outer data set instead of the data set returned from the stored procedure.

Any help?

Also, you haven't created the KVP when you call the stored procedure, so you can just do this

```
db.AddInParameter(comm, "@pRestId", DbType.Int32, row[0]); // or row[1], it isn't clear to me which you want to use.
```

Comment: Yeah not sure if that's stopping me or not. Let me edit my code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it will help for you. 
you are returning List in your web method, web services transaltes into array. so better you return Array, so that it can be serialized easily by using ToArray(); [Webservice and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628579/cant-transfer-listt-to-web-service)

1. Use dictionary, it will work with your [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)