# Send list of data object from client to web service

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, web-services

I have one online database on web service and one offline database on client computer (just in case the network doesn't work, the system still can work). I want to sync those two database when user click the button on the window control. So I use one web method to receive a list of data from client.

```
[WebMethod]
public bool updateNewMenu(List<Menu> mn) {
    return !(m.updateNM(mn)) ? true : false;
}
```

On the client computer I try to send a list of data but there is a error

```
private void btnUploadMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Menu> m = dbc.Menus.ToList();

        if (!mywebservice.updateNewMenu(m))
        {
             //do something if cannot send data
        }
    }
```

The error says

> "The best overloaded method match for
>   'WoB.com.somee.wswob.WOBWS.updateNewMenu(WoB.com.somee.wswob.Menu[])'
>   has some invalid arguments". "cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'WoB.com.somee.wswob.Menu[]'"

Those 2 databases have the same structure but somehow it can't convert the list of this one to another.

Is there anyway that I can do that?

Comment: You've made your code harder to read then need be here.  Anyway, what does `updateNM` of `m.updateNM(mn)` do?

Comment: I use window form project so I couldn't see Configure Service Reference. But I tried to remove and add again with CollectionType of System.Collections.Generic.List but still didn't work...

Comment: m is one class of web service and updateNM is a method of that class. updateNM receive a list of Menu and update it into database on webservice.

Comment: What happens if you change this line `List<Menu> m = dbc.Menus.ToList();` to `var m = dbc.Menus.ToArray();`?

Comment: "cannot convert from 'WoB.Menu[]' to 'WoB.com.somee.wswob.Menu[]'"
This is the new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to reconfigure your Service Reference

- Go to your Service Reference folder
- Right click on the Service class.
- Choose Configure Service Reference
- Change the CollectionType combo to System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Yeah, I did it already. Actually, I use winform project so I don't have Configure Service Reference. I just simply removed the web reference and add it again with that option, but it didn't work anyway...

Comment: I see, my misunderstanding. You are using WebServices not WCF so perhaps [this question could help you more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628579/cant-transfer-listt-to-web-service)

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. I want to ask if I change Webservice to WCF, can I achieve my target without changing to much source code?

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure, but I am certain that you should plan to switch to WCF if the constraints (time, costs) allow you to do so. See [What is the difference between WebServices and WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services)